# Density and SOS polynomials

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, sums-of-squares

Is the set of sum of square (SOS) polynomials dense (in a sense to precise) in the set of non negative polynomials of degree less than $d$?

I don't even know how to ask a well posed question... here I don't preceise the topology, should we look the Zariski topology or else ?

In fact, my idea would be to relax a constraint of the form 
$$
p(x)>0
$$ where $f$ is a polynomial by the constraint
$$
p(x)= SOS(x)
$$

maybe other notions than density is better ...

Comment: Are you asking about polynomials on $\mathbb R$?  A real poynomial that takes no negative values is equal to a finite sum of squares of real polynomials. I can post a proof if you ask me to.

Comment: I am interested in multivariate polynomials.
I don"t know the result, I am interested by ideas of this demonstration.

What I know is the Putinar certificate. It states that if we are given a closed semi-algebraic set $K=\{x, g_i(x)\ge 0\}$ then every nonnegative polynomials can be written as
$P = \sigma_0(x) + \sum_i \sigma_i(x) g_i(x)$ where $\sigma_i$'s are SOS.
See the introduction of
http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~vicki/preprint/ratrepcompact.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked myself the very same question and found the Theorem 4.1 in this [reference](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.2406&rep=rep1&type=pdf). It seems that your intuition was correct.